# Split FlowContent by line and extract text to attributes NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

Im using NIFI and i want to extract attributes of my file lines .

My Filetext looks like this :

```
DEV=A9E ,SEN=1
DEV=B9E ,SEN=2
...
```

And i want to split text by line and then extract dev and sen to attribute , any way to do this with NIFI, i have tried split text and split content but I can't see how can I split text by line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SplitText with a Line Count of 1 is generally the approach to split a text file line-by-line. It will use \r, \n, or \r\n as the end of a line.

ExtractText would be used to parse each line and extract parts of the line into flow file attributes. You need to come up with a regular expression that uses capture groups to capture the parts you are interested in.